# Paypal Pay Later button set a specific language?

Tags: button, paypal

is there a way to display the dynamic Paypal Pay Later buttons in a specific langauge? I tried setting the locale like:

```
<script
src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client- 
id=myid123&locale=en_US&currency=EUR&components=messages"
data-namespace="PayPalSDK">
</script>
```

But it stays in German instead.

Also tried using VPN and the language isnt changing based on IP.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your question about buttons, or offer messaging?

Text of the buttons can be set with `locale`.

Text of the messaging is specific to the business account that will be processing payments. If it is a DE account, [the information here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/pay-later/de/) applies. Nothing about en_US or US buyers. Read the Eligibility section carefully.

Comment: Hey, thanks it is about the pay later messages. So no way to display those depending on website language then? That's unfortunate but not surprising for Papyal I guess.